# Update field in mongodb collection object based on old value

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to update fields in a MongoDB collection object based on their old values. My task involves encoding certain fields in all MongoDB documents from a specific collection. I'm wondering if there's a way to update a field based on its old value, perhaps using a callback API or a similar approach. My project is written in Java.

I've attempted to update the collection as follows: I first retrieve all documents from the collection and then iterate over each document, using updateOne based on the document ID.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can _"update fields in a MongoDB collection object based on their old values"_ by using a [pipeline in the update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).